# Adding an bump node to an emission / image texture

Tags: node-editor, bump

I would like to add a bit of height (bump) to the moon texture here but since I am no node expert all my attempts failed.

Is there a way to add a bump node to the image texture in order to make the moon texture more visible?

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: technically, you can use Principled BSDF instead of that mix shader and connect all into it with bump node connected to normal

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do with your node setup, how does your image texture look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're going for, but this is how I would go about setting up something like that. The image must enter the Bump node in *non-color* space (hence the convert to B&W), and the BaseColor should run through a Diffuse shader which will allow a Normal input (unless you're going for something specific like "toon" or "unshaded"). I also recommend using a Fresnel as a Mix Factor between the emission and the Diffuse, if you want the emission to be part of a "glowy atmosphere" effect (note that I lowered the IOR to 1.05 to achieve this effect).

[image: Glow]

Another alternative is to use Displacement (though I still recommend the Fresnel). Keep the scale below 0.2 0r 0.1 for the best effect, but you might find even smaller (0.05) works even better:

[image: Glow2]

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Some Texture node -> Connect to Bump node as height -> Connect to normal Map node as height -> Connect to Principled BSDF as normal.

Comment: A Bump node output should not be connected to a Normal Map node and a Normal Map node does not have a "height" input. This answer seems confused.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).